# Why is my CSS Grid container off by 1 pixel?

Tags: css, browser, frontend, css-grid, display

When I inspect my layout grid container in Chrome DevTools, it appears that my grid is pushed to the right by 1 pixel. I'm able to see the left-side border of the grid but the right-side border is off-screen.

Screenshot of issue:[image: Off-by-1 CSS Grid container]

What could be the cause of this issue?

I have the following global css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And the following CSS for my grid container:

```
.container {
  background-color: #F5F6F9;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px minmax(1080px, 1fr) 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 75px minmax(150px, 1fr) 75px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header header header"
  ". main ."
  "footer footer footer";
}
```

I thought perhaps adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the global css would fix the issue but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the solution you are looking for, but HTML body have a safe space of 8px as its margin. So when you set the margin: 0px; , you also remove the safe space along with it. However, you can always set the margin-right to 1px so you can see the border.

Forced method, change your body margin:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```